# How to fix syntax error mysqli 1064 error

Tags: mysql

ım working localhost, after my work end. I want a upload my db server phpmyadmin. But still syntax error how can ı fix this?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
>   ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO' at line 7 )

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `veriler`;
CREATE TABLE `veriler`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kullanici` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gpa` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `durumu` int(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `miktari` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tarih` datetime(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: On local or server?

Comment: maybe you are using an old mysql server version ... try using TYPE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ... or remove  ENGINE = InnoDB  ...

Comment: version on both local and server ...

Comment: The one which is giving you the error...

Comment: This query is working on MySQL version 5.7.19. Please check your MySQL version.

Comment: This syntaxes ok in mariadb 10.1.14 You may want to check the docs for version changes from your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for fractional seconds in `DATETIME` values wasn't added until version MySQL 5.6. If you can't upgrade your server, you will need to remove the trailing `(6)` from the definition of column `tarih` i.e.

```
`tarih` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

Note that you will lose precision in those values relative to your MariaDB server. If you need to store microseconds in your data values, you will need to upgrade the MySQL server to version 5.6 or later.

Comment: @Vedat good to hear. Just make note of the comment I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified version:

```
CREATE TABLE `veriler` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kullanici` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gpa` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `durumu` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `miktari` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tarih` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: thanks but still error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHA' at line 7

Comment: Can you run this query and show me the result: `SELECT version();`

Comment: remove `USING BTREE` from the query and run it again.

Comment: on localhost: 10.1.37-MariaDB
server : 5.5.55